# What is "Data point spacing" in fiber optics?

Tags: fiber-optics

I was going through documents related to Optical Fiber communication. There to define optical fiber, parameter "data point spacing" is used. I tried googling, but there is no proper explanation any where. Can someone tell me what exactly it is.

Comment: please post a link to the document or quote the pertinent paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I would try Googling instead of "goggling."  In less than 10 seconds I found your term to be the definition of the distance resolution capability of an OTDR machine.  Thus, a "data point spacing" of ,e.g., 5 cm indicates the OTDR can tell you where an event occurred to within 5cm of the exact location on the fiber line.